# Bulk Upload SMIME certs

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api, smime

I have many SMIME certs that needs to upload on each user. Now, I am doing it manually, one by one. Question is, is it possible to upload multiple SMIME certificates using Apps Script or something?

I've tried to browse the GSuite admin but I cant find the upload multiple certs there.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Gmail API supports uploading S/MIME certificates to users. So in Appscripts, you can use the [smimeInfo()](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs/smimeInfo/insert) method. 
You need your userId (or put 'me') and the email address of the user that will receive the certificate.
You will also have to set the S/MIME email [config](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs/smimeInfo#resource).

This script is adapted from the [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/apps-script)  to loop over all the users of your domain and upload the certificate to each one:

```
function main() {  
   var optionalArgs = {
    customer: 'my_customer',
    orderBy: 'email'
  };  
  //Change the string, boolean etc to the parameters of the certificate you have been using.
  var smimeObj = {"id": string,
          "issuerCn": string,
          "isDefault": boolean,
          "expiration": long,
          "pem": string,
          "pkcs12": bytes,
          "encryptedKeyPassword": string
        };
  var userId = 'me';

  var response = AdminDirectory.Users.list(optionalArgs);
  var users = response.users;

  if (users && users.length > 0) {

    for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {

      var user = users[i];
      var sendAsEmail = user.primaryEmail;
      Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.SmimeInfo.insert(smimeObj, userId, sendAsEmail)


    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No users found.');
  }
}
```